# Simplifing WsSecurity to JaxWS metro Implementation

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, ws-security, java-metro-framework

I'm using JaxWs Metro project implementation and i'm using this tutorial to add Ws Security feature to my web services.
http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-java/web-services/jax-ws/secure-usernametoken-java-web-services-using-metro-wsit/

What i have understand is that to add a Ws Security to your web service.You must first generate manually the wsdl file then add WSIT configuration part to your web service then put that modified wsdl in your project and modify sun-jaxws.xml so that take care of your modified wsdl file(so that it will not generate a new one).
I think it's extremley difficult to do all that for all my web services.In addition,i'm using eclipse so there is no generating tool(like netbeans).
I want to know is there any simple solution ?